# Simple regex to eliminate "/" and number after it

Tags: java

I am new to programming and I am trying to eliminate sum characters in my string using JAVA with regex. How do I go about and do this.

```
string = "711 / 70,504";
//expected: 711
```

Comment: Your title says \ your code has / but in description you said "sum characters" (which may be understood as `+`). So which is it? Also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) so far?

Comment: Will there only ever be a number after the slash? Or will there be some strings like `"foo / bar"` where you want to keep the `" / bar"`?

Comment: The format is unclear, if it's anything after slash, you can remove `/[^/]*$`

Answer (score 2):

Can be easily done with the `String.substring` method, without needing a regexp:

```
String string = "711 / 70,504";
string = string.substring(0, string.indexOf(" /"));
```

Alternatively, if you really want to use a regex, you can use `String.replaceAll`:

```
String string = "711 / 70,504";
string = string.replaceAll("\\s*/.*", "");
```